# Error when exporting Chinese with bytearrayoutputstream in java

Tags: java

These are java codes.And it just the small test of "ByteArrayOutputStream",When I practice according to the teaching video, compile through, the execution result is garbled, do not know where the wrong

```
package com.xiaoyin.otherIO;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create a buffer output stream object to write data
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Create input stream objects, realize data reading, connect a txt text, which has several in both English and Chinese
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("d.txt");
    // Reading data
    int b = -1;
    while ((b = fis.read()) != -1) {
        // Store all the data you read in memory
        baos.write(b);
    }``
    // Remove all data from the buffer and convert it to a byte array
    byte[] arr = baos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(new String(arr));
    // Turn off the input stream
    fis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using the default system encoding. Try `new String(arr, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)